# A detail in proving that a sequence of uniformly integrable random variables converges weakly.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I would like to prove the following result that is stated in a textbook, but I am not able to grasp a couple of details in the proof.

Let $\{X_n: n \in N\} $ be a sequence of uniformly integrable random variables on some probability space . There there is a subsequence which converges weakly in $L^1(P); $ i.e., there is a random variable $X $ such that
$$ E[X_nZ] \to E[XZ] $$
for every random variable $Z\in L^\infty(P). $

The idea provided is to start with a sequence of random variables like
$$ X_{n,k} = X_n\cdot 1_{\{|X_n|\le k\}}  $$
for each $k. $
This sequence is bounded in $L^2 $ by construction and therefore there exists a subsequence which
converges weakly in $L^2 $  (is there a special name for this result?)
Then, and this is where I have my real issue, they asy that by the Cantor diagonalization procedure, we can extract a single subsequence $\{n_j: j \in N\} $ such that
$$ X_{n_j,k} \to L_k $$
weakly for each $k. $
I fail to see how I can extract a single sequence that converges to $L_k $ starting for example from the sequence $X_{1,1}, X_{2,1}, X_{3, 1}, \ldots $ If my recollection is correct, I need to keep using subsequences of subsequences to make the Cantor diagonalization process work.  But, how is a
subsequence of $X_{1,2}, X_{2,2}, X_{3,2}, \ldots, $ a subsequence of the first one?

I tried everything I could think, but nothing.  The rest of the proof I can see, but this Cantor "thing", I cannot.

Any insight offered greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
Maurice.

PS I have barely a modicum of exposure to Functional Analysis and I wonder if this result has something to do with the Dunford-Pettis theorem.

Comment: You cut down to a subsubsequence for $k=2$, then a subsubsubsequence for $k=3$, etc.  If you make appropriate control of the rates of convergence of these subsubsub...subsequences, your diagonal subsequence will converge.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? If I start say with a subsequence for k=1, k=2, k=3, etc...  How do I choose the subsequence according to Cantor diagonalization scheme so that it converges to L1, L2, L3, etc....     This is what I am not seeing..   All random variables in the sequence for k=1 are bounded in absolute value by 1. those for k=2 are bounded by 2. If L2 were equal to , say1.5, how can a sequence that converges to something in [-1,1] converge to 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

Extract from $\left(X_{n,1}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ a subsequence $\left(X_{n_k^{(1)},1}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ which converges wealky to some $L_1$.
Then extract from $\left(X_{n_k^{(1)},2}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ a subsequence
$\left(X_{n_k^{(2)},2}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ converging weakly to some $L_2$ in $L^2$. By definition, $\{n_k^{(2)},k\geqslant 1\}\subset \{n_k^{(1)},k\geqslant 1\}$.

Now we can continue the process: suppose that we found sequences of integers $\{n_k^{(1)},k\geqslant 1\},\dots,\{n_k^{(i)},k\geqslant 1\}$ such that
$$
\{n_k^{(i)},k\geqslant 1\}\subset \{n_k^{(i-1)},k\geqslant 1\}\subset\dots\subset\{n_k^{(1)},k\geqslant 1\}
$$
and $\left(X_{n_k^{(u)},u}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ converges to some $L_u$ weakly in $L^2$. We have to find an increasing sequence of integers $(n_k^{(i+1)})_{k\geqslant 1}$ such that  $\{n_k^{(i+1)},k\geqslant 1\}\subset \{n_k^{(i)},k\geqslant 1\}$ and $\left(X_{n_k^{(i+1)},i+1}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ converges to some $L_{i+1}$ weakly in $L^2$. To do so, extract from $\left(X_{n_k^{(i)},i+1}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ a weakly convergent subsequence in $L^2$.

To sum up, we found increasing sequences of integers $(n_k^{(i)})_{k\geqslant 1}$, $i\geqslant 1$ such that

- for each $i\geqslant 1$, $\{n_k^{(i+1)},k\geqslant 1\}\subset \{n_k^{(i)},k\geqslant 1\}$ and
- for each $i\geqslant 1$, $\left(X_{n_k^{(i)},i}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ converges to some $L_i$ weakly in $L^2$.

To conclude, let $n_k:= n_k^{(k)}$; by the first bullet, $(X_{n_k,i})$ is a subsequence of $(X_{n_k^{(i)},i})$ for all $i$.

Comment: Thank you Davide. The description is very clear. I follow the diagonal argument very well, no problem there. However, I still have one issue, just one. I get the first sequence $\{X_{n,1}\} $ and how to extract a subsequence from it that converges to $L_1. $ No problem there. But now, I take a further subsequence and for it I consider $X(n_k^{(1)}, 2) $ This is where I am having a hard time. If the first terms were either 0 or random variables in $[-1, 1] $, when I consider the second subsequence aren't these also 0 or bounded by $[-1, 1]. $? .... this is my crux.

Comment: Or perhaps do you mean that after I select the variables in the first subsequence,  I "filter" the original variables via the$I_{|X_n|\le k} $? In other words, I am not now filtering the $X_{n_j, 1} $ but the original $X_{n_j} $.. If I do this then things make sense. For some reason I guess that I was assumed that the original random variables were only used in creating $X_{n,1} $ and then I was applying the conditions to these which would only change the variables that were set to zero in $X_{n,1} $ but the others would remain equal to themselves.  That is what confuses me in the definition.

Comment: @Maurice Paradoxally, it seems that this particular setting makes the things more complicated. Actually, all you need in the following: for each $k\geq 1$ suppose that the  sequence $(Y_{n,k})_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded in $L^2$. Then using the above procedure,  there is an  increasing sequence of integers $(n_i)$  and random variables $L_k,k\geq 1$ such that $(Y_{n_i,k})_k$ converges weakly in $L^2$ tp $L_k$ for  all $k$. Then apply this to $Y_{n,k}=X_n\cdot 1_{\{|X_n|\le k\}}$.

Comment: Thank you, again, Davide. If you allow me one last request for clarification, please. I understand the diagonal scheme. My only doubt is about what I use as subsequences. Say we start with $Y_{n,1} = X_n\cdot 1_{\{|X_n}\le 1\}}. $ It is bounded in L2 and it has a convergent subsequence. Perfect. Now for the diagonal argument I need to pick another subsequence from this subsequence. But all elements in $\{Y_{n,1}\} $ are either 0 or r.v.'s bounded in $[-1,1]. $ So, only elements $Y_{n_k,2} =1_{\{|X_{n,k}|\le 2}  $ is different from $Y_{n_k,1} $ has to be one of those that were set to zero ?